# How to search files in node-inspector

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I'm using node-inspector on Ubuntu for the first time, trying to debug an Express application.

When I run the program and open `http://0.0.0.0:8080/debug?port=5858` in Chromium or Google Chrome, it seems to work, and all the scripts are loaded in the "Scripts" tab.

But there are hundreds of files and there seems to be missing an option to:

- Collapse the Scripts Tree to see the directories only
- Or search files in the tree.

Is there an option for this anywhere, or an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome you can search source files with the shortcut `Ctrl + O`.

Comment: has this changed between versions of chrome? ctrl + o opens a file dialog for me.

Comment: you have to first open Developer Tools (ctrl + shift + i).

Comment: even with the node inspector developer tools-ish window already up?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to filter scripts by filename, although I also have this same problem and have hunted around. The only improvement I have found is if you use the [Google Chrome Canary](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs) build, you have an option to display as a tree of collapsible folders or a flat list of file paths.

Comment: Even am struggling to search files in node-inspector but I don't see the option to display file paths as flat list as you mentioned. can you guide how to switch between these 2 options.